# WordPress installation in a sub folder

Tags: wordpress

I have two installations of WordPress on installed in public_html folder that maps to http://heroleads.com/ and another installation that maps to http://heroleads.com/thailand/

I followed the instructions https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

The installation in the sub folder is extremely slow, the problem comes loading the first byte which takes around 15 seconds. I stopped all the plugins and changed the theme to twenty fifteen the problem remained.

I change .htaccess settings and permalinks settings but the problem remains. What could be the issue?

Comment: That's weird, the fact that the installation is in a subfolder shouldn't impact performance. Does the two installations are the same? (same plugins etc)

Comment: It is driving me crazy, each installation is different in terms of theme and plugins. I stopped all the plugins and the theme to remove any doubts but the same result. still slow. I can not figure out the cause of this issue

Comment: Could you try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/)? It monitor the load time - after install it check on the detailed timeline graph, it should tell you if it come from the WP Core - if not then it will mean that it's server related.